# data for panorama stitching testing

Tags: stitching, panorama

I want some data (images that have only shift) to test on [xuvtools](http://www.xuvtools.org/download)  or [Microsoft ICE](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/groups/ivm/ice/) and my own software.
Is there any available?

Answer (score 2):

From a simple Google search...

http://sourceforge.net/adobe/adobedatasets/panoramas/home/Home/ 
http://www.ti.uni-bielefeld.de/html/research/avardy/index.html 
http://sun360.mit.edu/ 
http://www.iiia.csic.es/~aramisa/datasets/iiiapanos.html 
http://www.visualsize.com/mosaic3d/index.php

Comment: Ok, I take a look at them, but I need panorama images that have only shift.